# SSH + Ping fails when accessing virtual machines from physical machine

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, networking, ssh, ping

I currently have two virtual machines setup and running on one physical machine, which I need to access via another physical machine.

I have configured each of the virtual machines with a resolvable IP address. Each of the virtual machines are able to ping each other via the `ping ###.###.#.###` command.

However, when I attempt to ping the virtual machines from my physical machine, the ping fails. I'm also unable to SSH into the virtual machines from my physical machine. It may be worth noting that the machine with the VMs is on a different network than the physical machine.

The physical machine is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as the native OS. I recently installed the os on this machine. Are there any additional steps I'm missing here in making my virtual machines accessible by my physical machine on a different network?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is sshd set up on the VMs

Comment: Yes, SSH is setup on the Vms. Pinging the VMs from the physical machine also fails, as does pinging the physical machine from the VMs.

Comment: Is the network on their host set to `bridged networking ` too?

Comment: Yes, when I check on the VirtualBox Network settings tab I can see that each of these virtual machines is set to use a bridged adapter. The physical machine I'm not sure how to check / if it is required?

Comment: I suppose you are using a router, if so port forwarding should help.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Do you have a link to some additional information on getting going with port forwarding? I assume I'll probably have to reconfigure my virtual machines? It should be noted that I have configured each of these virtual machines with a resolvable IP address and the VMs are able to be accessed by another server (a hosted Chef server).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/

Comment: Per this link https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/, I can see that the option to enable / configure port forwarding in virtualbox is only available if using a NAT network type. I do not have the option available to me to configure port forwarding in virtualbox, so I assume I am not using a NAT network type?

Comment: I  am not a network expert but I believe the problem is as a result of the fact that the other computer is on a different network so you need to open a port to your host which has the VMs installed

Answer (score 0):

I think that there may be a firewall issue.

I just opened 2 VM's that I have, one Win10, one Ubuntu, both of which are setup as having bridged network devices. I can ping the Ubuntu VM from the host, and vice versa, and I can ping the host from within the Win10 VM, but I cannot ping the Win10 machine from the host.

Comment: My host for the virtual machines is indeed a windows machine. Windows 7 host running two Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machines. From these two virtual machines, I am not able to ping an Ubuntu 16.04 physical machine, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was having my VM host machine and my physical machine on separate networks. Upon connecting my physical machine to the same network as the VM host machine, I am able to ping / ssh into the virtual machines.

Hope this helps anybody with a similar issue!